# jQuery check if attr = value

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, attr, if-statement

I seem to be having trouble with my code. I need to say:

```
if ( $('html').attr('lang').val() == 'fr-FR' ) {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

When I check the console, I just get an error telling me this isn't a function. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You should be using `data()` for this sort of thing.

Comment: No. Html does have a attribute called lang.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Just remove the .val(). Like:

```
if ( $('html').attr('lang') == 'fr-FR' ) {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

Comment: You answered to quickly dude, I have to wait 5 more minutes in order to accept it :)

Comment: You often want to check the `class` attribute for a value, but `class` attr can have multiple values separated by space, like this `<div id="mydiv" class="one two three"></div>` so in that case you can use the function `hasClass()` to check for a value like so `$( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "two" )`

Answer (score 14):

jQuery's [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method returns the value of the attribute:

> The `.attr()` method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such as jQuery's `.each()` or `.map()` method.

All you need is:

```
$('html').attr('lang') == 'fr-FR'
```

However, you *might* want to do a case-insensitive match:

```
$('html').attr('lang').toLowerCase() === 'fr-fr'
```

---

jQuery's [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method returns the value of a form element.

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the `.val()` method returns an array containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns `null`.

Comment: Very thorough, great response. Thanks.