# Is there a faster way of selecting elements if the data attribute contains a value?

Tags: jquery, performance

Is there a more preferred way of doing this in terms of performance?

Example HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-attr="ABC XYZ" />
<div data-attr="XYZ"></div>
```

Example jQuery:

```
var myValue = 'XYZ';
$('[data-attr*="' + myValue + '"]').hide();
```

Is using classes better for this?

Comment: `$('[data-attr^="' + myValue + '"]').hide();` Use attribute contains word selector. It must be efficient than contains selector.

Comment: @Tushar I need it to be controlled by the JS

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211222/jquery-check-if-attr-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing between data-attr show/hide vs. class show/hide, the difference is about **20%** at **1,000,000** iterations. But, user experience doesn't necessarily seem affected by this in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the selector only to `input` elements:

```
$('input[data-attr*="' + myValue + '"]').hide();
```

It reduces the surface area that the jQuery selector has to operate on

Comment: I would but I have these data attributes on all types of elements.