# Check if data attribute value equals a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element that has a my custom attribute on a `<button class="navbar-toggle">` element called `data-toggle-wmc` and I am trying to check whether the attribute value equals a string value called `collapse` somehow it has not worked so far.

I tried the following

```
if ($('button.navbar-toggle').attr('data-toggle-wmc') === 'collapse') {
     alert('123yes');
}
```

I also tried

```
if ($('button.navbar-toggle').attr('data-toggle-wmc') == 'collapse') {
     alert('123yes');
}
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211222/jquery-check-if-attr-value) question but somehow the condition is not being fullfilled.

Comment: You're missing a `'` - `.attr('data-toggle-wmc')`. Also, use `data('toggle-wmc') == 'collpase'` instead

Comment: I don't know if its a typo but you are missing a ` ' ` after `data-toggle-wmc)`

Comment: It is only a typo on this question, but not on my actual code.

Comment: Do you have only one element for selector `button.navbar-toggle`?

Comment: In which case your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/f53o5dwL/. This means either you have multiple `button.navbar-toggle` elements, the element doesn't have the attribute - hence my suggestion above to use `data()` as it may be added to jQuery's cache, not the DOM, or there is an error elsewhere in your code and you need to check the console to see it. In any of the above cases we need to see more of your HTML and JS code in order to help you effectively.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Possibly there are multiple element, so `$('button.navbar-toggle').attr('data-toggle-wmc')` will return value of first element that might be the reason of not working as desired by OP

Comment: Seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/bhkv76gf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($('button.navbar-toggle').data('toggle-wmc') === 'collapse') ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it didn't work, but `console.log($('button.navbar-toggle').data('toggle-wmc'))` does print out the attribute value.

Comment: as also other pointed out (with examples) the code works, so probably there's something else in your code that shomehow interferes with that. for example another button with classe `.navbar-toggle` in the page. What if you put the console.log _just before_ the if? does it still print the value correctly or not?

Comment: Yep @LorenzoMarcon is right. Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/dun6qvn0/

Comment: Thank you this method works. I will mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Access data properties with $.data. it seems to work like this

```js
$("button.navbar-toggle").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).data("toggle-wmc") === "collapse"){
    console.log($(this).data("toggle-wmc"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle-wmc="collapse"  width="100" height="50">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an argument error in your code. Try this

```
if ($('button.navbar-toggle').attr('data-toggle-wmc') == 'collapse') {
    alert('123yes');
  }
```