# Using Jquery for an IF statement based on an attribute value string

Tags: jquery, html

Im using this element

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" state="login">
```

and the script

```
$("#toggleLogin").click(function() {

    if ($("#exampleModal").data("state") === "login") { alert("it works"); } else { alert ("not working");};



<script `src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
```

I look forward having an script, that if the value of "state" is 'login' it will be switched to 'signup' and else will be 'login' back again

I've found this example here but it's not working for me

[Check if data attribute value equals a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848950/check-if-data-attribute-value-equals-a-string)

Comment: why do you think this is php related? You tagged it as such.

Comment: It looks strange that you want to toggle a data attribute's value of a bootstrap modal... What will it be used for if you don't event know how to change the value? Is your next question about how to change the modal's conent based on it? What do you really want to do here?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes, I want to have the signup form hidden (just few extra fields) and have them displayed when the data-state value is signup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reordering your scripts to include jQuery in advance. Then change `state="login"` to `data-state="login"` in `#exampleModal` tag.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-state="login"></div>

<button id="toggleLogin">Toogle Login</button>


<script>
$("#toggleLogin").click(function() {

    if ($("#exampleModal").data("state") === "login") {
        $("#exampleModal").data("state", "signup");
    } else {
        $("#exampleModal").data("state", "login");
    }
    console.log($("#exampleModal").data("state"));
    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your snippet does not toggle anything.

Comment: @Chaska Thank you!!! you mean the green check right? I just did it! first time in stack overflow.

Comment: now, how would you make visible/hidden a DIV element based on other element's data attribute ? (if its signup or login)